# dropzone.js not uploading

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I set up a simple dropzone.js by following the tutorial on the dropzon website by [StarTutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php). It shows the dropzone correctly and when I drop files into it the will show up but when I try to click the upload button nothing happens.
I am using this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="zone"></form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this PHP code:

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a while ago. It is due to indexing. Dropzone uploads multiple files at the same time. Thus file name is in array. Read the file using key with foreach or forloop. I used this in CodeIgniter:

```
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error)  {
    if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {                
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        $file_extension = end((explode(".", $name))); # extra () to prevent notice

        $targetPath = FCPATH . $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

        $file_new_name = uniqid(). '.'. $file_extension;

        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $file_new_name  ;  //5

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Any JS error shows in the console?
2. Have you tried to debug the PHP cod? Is the "uploads" folder writable?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add a submit button, a method and a enctype to your form.

`<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="zone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" /><!-- Submit button -->
</form>`

Your dropzonejs form does show the pictures or files you would like to upload only but dropzonejs dousn't upload any of your files to your server, you will need to submit the files to your server using php or server side javascript..

I hope this will be helpful for you..